# Can zsh `else` reserved keyword command be aliased and the lexem itself be repurposed as `fi` keyword command?

Tags: zsh-alias

Following [ZSH: Call in-built function from zsh function that uses the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498409/zsh-call-in-built-function-from-zsh-function-that-uses-the-same-name) and [Run a command that is shadowed by an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias#39296), it might be expected that a command `keyword` equivalent of what `builtin` and `command` are doing for their respective eponymous token category; so that

```
if [ -z 'love' ]; then echo 'sad world'; keyword else echo 'wonderful world'; fi
```

would be equivalent to

```
if [ -z 'love' ]; then echo 'sad world'; else echo 'wonderful world'; fi
```

This problem was found in the following tricky scenario: being able to replace `else` with `alie` and `fi` with `else`. See [Can zsh buildtins be aliased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999451/can-zsh-buildtins-be-aliased) for more details.

So an hypothetical attempt to implement that, if the `keyword` command existed, would be:

alias alie="keyword else"
  alias else='fi'

So, to sum it up, the question is how do you make the following peace of zsh code works as expected by the previous command:

```
if [ -z 'love' ]; then echo 'sad world'; alie echo 'wonderful world'; else
```

Comment: Related resources: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148484/how-to-disable-a-shell-keyword

Comment: According to [the builtin documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) `disable -r else` should disable the `else` keyword, but it lakes explicit example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet a working solution, but here is an idea: using the `-r` flag of `enable` and `disable` builtin commands to change visibility of the `else` keyword. So:

```
alias se='enable -r else; if'
alias alie='else'
disable -r else
alias else="fi; disable -r else"
```

This unfortunately doesn't work

```
se [ -z 'amo' ]; then echo 'trista mondo'; alie echo 'mirinda mondo'; else
# zsh: parse error near `fi'
```

This is however really on the "else" substitution that something break, as a non-inline version will indeed enter the else-branch and print "mirinda mondo".